# jwerty key unbinding

Tags: javascript, jquery

taken from: https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty

Does anyone know how to unbind after setting up a .key binding?

As a test, I want this set globally when something is selected

`jwerty.key('↑', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('up');
});`

then unbound when that object is unselected.  That stuff is already set up, inside that unselect statement though I want to call the jwerty unbind but can't figure out how.

but when I a) don't know how to unbind it explicitly or b) if I try to change it to a different anonymous function I still see the alert.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Does it not do what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a global key handler that can be removed, you have to bind it using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/LxQ4H/2/

```
function doit() {
  alert('up');
}
// to bind use namespaces so it can be unbound without removing
$(document.body).bind('keydown.test', jwerty.event('↑', doit));

// a button that unbinds the key handler
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(document.body).unbind('keydown.test')
});
```

If you want the key handler to be scoped to an HTML element, you need to set the listener on the element, not globally. This will only fire if the element that it's bound to has focus. Just pass in a selector to bind a shortcut local to that element http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/LxQ4H/

```
jwerty.key('⌃+⇧+P/⌘+⇧+P', function () { [...] }, this, '#myinput');
```

If your element doesn't take focus by default (a div), you need to make it focusable by doing the following. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/LxQ4H/1/

```
// or 0, 1,2 3 if you want it to be tabbable
document.getElementById('#mydiv').tabIndex = -1;
```

These code samples came from https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty (same link you already mentioned)

Comment: Thanks!  I never knew you could bind to namespaces, that rocks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have jQuery available, as Juan Mendes mentioned, you can use jQuery's `bind()` method, with `jwerty.event`.

However there is another way to solve this. Using the current code you provided;

```
jwerty.key('↑', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); alert('up'); });
```

jwerty's internals will do the bind for you, but will add it under a special "keydown.jwerty" namespace. ([See this line of the codebase](https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty/blob/master/jwerty.js#L51)). So, following the code you already have, you just need to do this:

```
$(document.body).unbind('keydown.jwerty');
```

The cool thing about using [namespaces in jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) is that you can bind all jwerty events by also doing this:

```
$(document.body).unbind('.jwerty');
```

Comment: You can avoid to use e.preventDefault(); As written in the docs you can simply use jwerty.key('↑', false); before.